# ViewModel - repopulate form with new content after ajax requests

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

When I call an AJAX Get/Post, I can send a `ViewModel` of my form to my Controller methods. Is there a way to repopulate the form after this request with the new values of the `ViewModel`? What the right return of my method: a Json with the ViewModel or a View? Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    type: "GET",
    url: "SomeController/doSomething",
    success: function(myViewModel) {
        // How to repopulate my form with the new values?
    }
});

public class SomeController {

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DoSomething(MyViewModel model) {

        model.SomeProperty = "This property needs to be changed into the View.";

        // The right way is returning a Json with the ViewModel...
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        // or return some View?
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What will be returned is `HTML`. Can I suggest that you return a `PartailView(model)`, this way it can be used throughout the system, you do not need to `json` encode it just use `return PartialView(model)`. Put the Partial View in your `Shared` Folder.

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(MyViewModel model) {


    model.SomeProperty = "This property needs to be changed into the View.";


    return PartialView("MyPartialView", model);
}
```

Change the ajax to stringify the form, this will allow the model binding to work:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: JSON.stringify({model : $('#form').serialize() }),
    type: "GET",
    url: "SomeController/doSomething",
    success: function(myViewModel) {
        $('#myUlDropDownListID').replaceWith(myViewModel);
    }
});
```

In your `ajax` you need to replace the `HTML` with the return, in this case you have called in `myViewModel`. I.e. if it is a table then you would do

```
$('#myUlDropDownListID').replaceWith(myViewModel);
```

This will replace the table with the new HTML

Comment: Thanks for the answer, CR41G14. My doubt is: I have this field "@model.SomeProperty", and I send it trhu Ajax for my Controller, and return it. When return, if I use this "replaceWith" method, the right field will be repopulated? If I use "$('#form').replaceWith(myViewModel), all binded fields will be populated with the new values?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You are posting an entire form? What is the form's function?

Comment: I need to send a ViewModel with some values from my form to Controller. In that, I'll populate some collection thru the values of this ViewModel, and, on "success" function of my AJAX request, I want to fill a <ul> with the new values of this collection. The same for a DropDownList.

Comment: See edits, the model is probably null as you did not set the expected parameter "model" to be the data.

Comment: Well, I'm trying this way: I have a IEnumerable into my ViewModel. When I change the item into some dropdownlist, I call a controller method and populate that IEnumerable. I'm returning like a JSON. How to fill the dropdownlist "@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyEnumerable, new SelectList(Model.Enumerables, "ID", "Description"))" on success of the ajax get?

Comment: put the @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyEnumerable, new SelectList(Model.Enumerables, "ID", "Description")) into a Partial View which will accept your model type, your controller will populate this drop down and return. If you replace the current drop down list with this return then the model binding etc will still be in place